# how to know if the pixel color is black from a float 4

Tags: java, image-processing, opencl, jocl

I ask my question [how to know pixel color using t_sampler in jocl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340383/how-to-know-pixel-color-using-t-sampler-in-jocl)  in a different way
I want to konw if a pixel is black or white knowing that I am using t_sampler in my kernel

```
const sampler_t smp = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | //Natural coordinates
                      CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | //Clamp to zeros
                      CLK_FILTER_NEAREST; //Don't interpolate
```

Then I used

```
int2 coord = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    float4 pixel = read_imageui(input, smp, coord);
```

My question is: how to use the value pixel to know the color of the concerned pixel?

I am stuck from few days and I tried many solutions to solve this problem, If you need any clarifications I will respond. 
Here is my kernel code

```
const sampler_t smp = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | //Natural coordinates
                      CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | //Clamp to zeros
                      CLK_FILTER_NEAREST; //Don't interpolate
__kernel void basic(__read_only image2d_t input,__global float *result) 
{

   int gidX = get_global_id(0);
    int gidY = get_global_id(1);

int2 coord = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));

int2 posIn = {gidX, gidY};

      float4 pixel = read_imagef(input, smp, posIn);
if ((pixel.x==0.0) && (pixel.y==0.0) && (pixel.z==0.0) ){

result[gidX]=1;
}  else result[gidX]=0;
    }
```

Comment: You need to know what color scheme is used. Without you can't decode it.

Comment: I didn't understood what you meen by color scheme, can you explain to me how i could know it. Is there a function for it?

Comment: Try Google. It will help. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme your hardware will interpret memory depending on the selected color schema.

Answer (score 0):

Read the pixel using `read_imagef` (I recommend it instead of `read_imageui`, depending on the image format, especially since in your example you are assigning to a float4 variable; check the specification for which is appropriate for each image format). The float4 components returned can then be checked. `pixel.x` is the red, `pixel.y` is the green, `pixel.z` is the blue, and `pixel.w` is the alpha (1.0f if the source format doesn't have alpha). To check for black (as you ask in the subject of your question), just  check that .x and .y and .z are all 0.0.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but t seems that it always 0.0 You acan see my code kernel above, I used a colored image and the result is always 0. here is my kernel Code I used read_imagef.  Where do you think the problem is?????

Comment: How are you launching the kernel (clEnqueueNDRangeKernel)? Also, you have a race condition: multiple work items will write to the same `result` location (when gidX is the same and gidY is different). Try using an image as your output and start by just copying the pixel value or swapping Red and Green until you get things to work. There are many read_imagef examples.